# Why does boxing occur in the interpolation expression of int?

Tags: c#, string.format

For example, the following code:

```cs
int n=1;
string str=$"{n}";
```

But after adding `ToString()` explicitly, boxing will not happen.

```cs
int n=1;
//The compiler will recommend removing the explicit call of the ToString() method
string str=$"{n.ToString()}";
```

The book `CLR via C#` writes that `String.Format` will call the `ToString` method internally to get the string representation of the object.

Since the ToString method is called internally, why does the boxing occur in Example 1?

Comment: Related: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40133739/8967612), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8477322/8967612), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35144363/8967612).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Calling `ToString`" is not a magic way to prevent boxing. Boxing still happens if you called `ToString` *after* it has been boxed, which is the case with string interpolation.

As you know, string interpolations generally desugars to `string.Format` calls. If you look at the [list of overloads available](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.format?view=netcore-3.1), you'll see that there isn't an overload that takes a value type like `int` or `long`. Every overload takes an `object`. To pass an `int` into these methods, it first needs to be boxed. `string.Format` then calls `ToString` at some point *on the boxed `object`*.

Compare this to directly calling `ToString` in the string interpolation. There is no conversion to a reference type (`object`), so no boxing.

Comment: Thank you~ I know that string.Format does not have an overload of int, but when I explicitly use ToString, the compiler recommends that remove the ToString method. Is this a problem with the compiler?

Comment: @yuxing no. You shouldn’t always use the most performant code at the cost of readability. You should only try to optimise where you really need it. Where you don’t really need it, strive for readability.

Answer (score 2):

I note that despite the fact your code is using a C# interpolated-string, it isn't using the `FormattedString` class as the C# compiler will only use `FormattedString` if the interpolated-string is being directly assigned to a `FormattedString`-typed variable, field or parameter (which I disagree with, but anyway).

> The book CLR via C# writes that String.Format will call the ToString method internally to get the string representation of the object.

Yes, but all of the `String.Format` overloads use `Object`-typed parameters or `params Object[]`, which necessarily means boxing its arguments.

> why does the boxing occur in Example 1?

Because it has to pass `int n` into `Object arg0`.

Here's the IL that gets generated when I compile your first block of code in LinqPad (C# 8.0, with compiler optimizations enabled):

```
IL_0000:  ldc.i4.1    
IL_0001:  stloc.0     
IL_0002:  ldstr       "{0}"
IL_0007:  ldloc.0     
IL_0008:  box         System.Int32
IL_000D:  call        System.String.Format
IL_0012:  pop         
IL_0013:  ret
```

You can see the `box` instruction at instruction offset `IL_0008`, right before it passes it into `String.Format`.

Comment: Some update/relief: in dotnet6 parameters of interpolated strings are not boxed anymore. The IL is changed from `String.Format` call to `DefaultInterpolatedStringHandler` `.AppendFormatted<Int32>(Int32)` call.

Answer (score -1):

In order to format a string, it can only take types of Object, to which it calls ToString() so that it can concatenate it. Boxing is basically turning a value type into a reference type, which is what happens in the implicit casting to object, so it can be stored in the heap.